# Javascript: Show/hide toggle first click not working

Tags: javascript

I am working on a page, and got this annoying issue.
The page has 10 figures, and the figcaptions are set to display:none as default. The effect I want is for a click on any image to show its respective caption, and hide any other captions.
Overall, it works well, but the first click on an image doesn't do anything.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

```
function toggle(figureNum){
  var captions = document.getElementsByTagName("FIGCAPTION");

  if (captions[figureNum].style.display == "none"){
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      captions[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    captions[figureNum].style.display = "block";
  } else {
    captions[figureNum].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: your `FIGCAPTION` elements initially don't have `style.display` defined

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces problem

Comment: Igor is probably right, depending on your CSS. Fix: `captions[figureNum].style.display != "block"`. Even better: Define a `.hidden { display: none; }` class and use ´element.classList.add("hidden")´ and ´element.classList.remove("hidden")´

Comment: Sure, here you go:  https://jsfiddle.net/cxt3sL4o/1/

Comment: I tried switching it to != "block", and that worked. I'd like to know how/why though, so I don't run into this again.

Comment: doesn't my comment above answer it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no `display` property set within the element's `style` property to begin with(`ele.style.display`). This means that it's an empty string, not `"none"`

```js
let caption = document.createElement("figcaption");
document.body.appendChild(caption);

console.log("display equals " + caption.style.display);
```

This does not mean that, if you have it set as `display: none` within your CSS that you cannot retrieve **that** value.

You can use `getComputedStyle(ele).getPropertyValue("display")` to pull the actual display styling applied by CSS whereas the styling within the element itself(*ele.style*) may not accurately reflect the properties set within CSS styling.

```js
    let caption = document.createElement("figcaption");
    document.body.appendChild(caption);
    
    console.log("display equals " + getComputedStyle(caption).getPropertyValue("display"));
```

```css
figcaption {
display: none;
}
```

In the end you can simply adjust your code to allow for the one-off eventuality of the `display` property on the element being an empty string, **or** you could pull the value directly from your CSS and compare that instead:

```js
function toggle(figureNum){
                var captions = document.getElementsByTagName("FIGCAPTION"),
                displayProp = getComputedStyle(captions[figureNum]).getPropertyValue("display");
                
                if (displayProp == "none"){
                    for (i = 0; i < captions.length; i++){
                        captions[i].style.display = "none";
                    }
                    captions[figureNum].style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    captions[figureNum].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
            
            
document.querySelector("img").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
toggle(0);
});
console.log(document.querySelector("figcaption").style.display);
```

```css
FIGCAPTION {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
<FIGCAPTION>BLAH BLAH BLAH</FIGCAPTION>
```

Comment: @user3602839 It's no problem! Learning that the DOM facing styling on the element isn't always the same as the processed CSS is one of those gotchas that you have no reason to know about until you run into something like this!